# Oracle best practice to store statistics and infos as key/value

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, oracle11g

**Problem:** I have a huge database with lots of tables and entries. My application is similar to a social network and in my database I've infos about user logged-in, users phone model, registration data... Number of page viewed, number of comments, replies... every info and user activity has a datetime reference. I have a web application used to manage my user and I want to include a statistic page. In this statistic page I want to show some data:

- how many user logged-in
- how many user registered in last 7 days
- how many Android VS iOS
- ...

I'm facing the problem on how to retrieve all these infos from the DB. Having a JPA level and using entities, is it possible to create a special `View` *Statistic* as key/value:

```
   Key      Value
   TotUser   200
   Android   100
   iOS       100
   NewUser    10
```

**Simple example:**

```
CREATE TABLE peoples 
    (
 id number(38), 
 name varchar(20), 
 os varchar(10)
 );

INSERT INTO peoples
(id, name, os)
VALUES
(1,'john', 'Android');

INSERT INTO peoples
(id, name, os)
VALUES
(2,'jane', 'iOS');
```

Is there a way to store my query in a VIEW or other object?

```
select count(*) from peoples; // as TotUser
select count(*) from peoples where os like 'Android'; // as Android
select count(*) from peoples where os like 'iOS'; // as iOS
```

and have a `STATISTIC` table with key/value as results of my queries?

```
   STATISTIC
   ---------------
   Key      Value
   ---------------
   TotUser   2
   Android   1
   iOS       1
```

**What I done:**
Now I created an object Statistic, I execute every single query and store informations inside the object Statistic, providing a key name. Is there a way to do all this through SQL, avoiding any modification on my querys in my Java application? Stored procedure? Reporting functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is a [`materialized view`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm#i29867)

I suggest creating mviews with refresh on demand with an interval of your choice.

You have two options to achieve your goal with materizlized views

1. Create a big mview using union all to gather all the stats.
2. Create several small mviews for each source table and a big main MVIEW to concatenate all.

Comment: Thanks, I managed by using simple and single View and a main View to concatenate all statistics.

Comment: Well, consider turning this view's into mviews and you could save the DB a lot of trouble (look at it as caching results).

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done with a single SQL statement and a single scan of the table, there's no need to do anything complicated unless this becomes too slow, in which case a MV might be the answer.

```
with all_cts as (
select os, count(*) as ct
  from peoples
 group by os
       )
select 'TotUser' as key, sum(ct) as value
  from all_cts
 union all
select *
  from all_cts
```

By utilising [sub-query factoring](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php) you query the table once and, effectively, create a tiny in-memory table, which you can then use twice.

If you then need to query for a single OS you can either just run the query or create this query as a view and query the view with a WHERE clause:

```
select * from my_view_with_everything where os = 'Android';
```

Comment: what if I need another statistic counter taken from another table: number of daily posts (select count(*) from posts where date = today)? Is it possible to improve your query with that info?

Comment: If it's another table, which has no relation to the others you'll have to UNION it on...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to haki suggestion, I solved my problem by using separate Views for every statistic and a global main View that concatenate all statistics:

```
CREATE TABLE peoples 
    (
 id number(38), 
 name varchar(20), 
 os varchar(10)
 );


INSERT INTO peoples
(id, name, os)
VALUES
(1,'john', 'Android');

INSERT INTO peoples
(id, name, os)
VALUES
(2,'jane', 'iOS');

CREATE VIEW Stat(key,value) AS
SELECT 
'Total registered users', count(*) from peoples;

CREATE VIEW StatA(key,value) AS
SELECT 
'Total users using Android', count(*) from peoples where os like 'Android';

CREATE VIEW StatI(key,value) AS
SELECT 
'Total users using iOS', count(*) from peoples where os like 'iOS';

CREATE VIEW StatTot(key,value) AS
SELECT key,value FROM Stat
UNION ALL
SELECT key,value FROM StatA
UNION ALL
SELECT key,value FROM StatI;
```

StatTot output: `select * from StatTot`

```
    KEY           VALUE
Total registered users  2
Total users using Android   1
Total users using iOS   1
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44964/1)

By using this solution, I can add at runtime new custom statistic and display them without the need to modify my web-application.